# Prevent defaultHttpResponseTransform to parse JSON like string

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS `defaultHttpResponseTransform` tries to figure out if data is json and tries to parse it:

```
function defaultHttpResponseTransform(data, headers) {
  if (isString(data)) {
    // Strip json vulnerability protection prefix and trim whitespace
    var tempData = data.replace(JSON_PROTECTION_PREFIX, '').trim();

    if (tempData) {
      var contentType = headers('Content-Type');
      if ((contentType && (contentType.indexOf(APPLICATION_JSON) === 0)) || isJsonLike(tempData)) {
        data = fromJson(tempData);
      }
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

However data in response in `text/plain` that is `swift` message, and looks like `JSON` but it is not. And when Angular tries to `JSON.parse` it, I get error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected number
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at fromJson (http://localhost:8080/WebEastGui/build/js/app-vendor.js:41198:14)

Is there a way to force Angular not to force parsing JSON like string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about `Overriding the Default Transformations Per Request` from [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Thanks for realy fast answer. That is what i need sipmle transformResponse: [function (data) {
                    return data;
                }] solve all my problems with default parsing.